# Multiple small deletes

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a PL/SQL script that loops over records of people (~4 million) and executes multiple updates (~100) and a single delete statement (all of these updates and delete are on different tables).  The problem I am facing is that the one delete statement takes about half the run time by itself.  I understand that when you execute a delete statement, it needs to update the index, but I find it rather ridiculous. I am currently testing this script with one thread using `dbms_parallel_execute` but I plan to multithread this script.

I am executing a query similar to the following:

```
DELETE FROM table1 t1
WHERE (t1.key1, t1.key2) IN (SELECT t2.key1, t2.key2
                               FROM table2 t2
                              WHERE t2.parm1 = 1234
                                AND t2.parm2 = 5678).
```

Following facts:

- Table2 (~30 million records) is ~10 times larger than table1 (~3 million records).
- There is a primary key on table1(key1, key2)
- There is a primary key on table2(key1, key2)
- There is an index on table2(parm1, parm2)
- I have disabled the foreign key constraint on table1(key1, key2) that references table2(key1, key2)
- There are no other constraints on table1, but many more constraints on table2.
- All triggers on table1 have been disabled
- The explain plan for this query comes up with a cost lower than that of many of my update statements (but I know this doesn't account for much).

Explain plan output:

```
    OPERATION                            OPTIONS                                                                                              OBJECT_INSTANCE                              OBJECT_TYPE                          OPTIMIZER                                                                                            SEARCH_COLUMNS                               ID                                           PARENT_ID                                    DEPTH                                        POSITION                                     COST                                         CARDINALITY                                  BYTES                                        CPU_COST                                     IO_COST                                      TIME                                         
------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------- 
DELETE STATEMENT                                                                                                                                                                                                            ALL_ROWS                                                                                                                                                                                     0                                                                                         0                                            5                                            5                                            1                                           36                                        38043                                            5                                            1 
DELETE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1                                            0                                            1                                            1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
NESTED LOOPS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             2                                            1                                            2                                            1                                            5                                            1                                           36                                        38043                                            5                                            1 
TABLE ACCESS                         BY INDEX ROWID                                                                                                                                  2 TABLE                                ANALYZED                                                                                                                                                                                     3                                            2                                            3                                            1                                            4                                            1                                           25                                        29022                                            4                                            1 
INDEX                                RANGE SCAN                                                                                                                                        INDEX                                ANALYZED                                                                                                                                        1                                            4                                            3                                            4                                            1                                            3                                            1                                                                                     21564                                            3                                            1 
INDEX                                UNIQUE SCAN                                                                                                                                       INDEX (UNIQUE)                       ANALYZED                                                                                                                                        2                                            5                                            2                                            3                                            2                                            1                                            1                                           11                                         9021                                            1                                            1
```

I was wondering if there were any way to make this delete go faster.  I tried to do a `bulk delete` but it didn't seem to improve the run time.  If there were any way to execute all the deletes and then update the index after, I suspect it would run faster.  Obviously doing a create table from a select is out of the picture since I am looping over records (and running through multiple conditions) from another table to do the delete.

Comment: Is your table by any chance index-organized? Try `SELECT IOT_TYPE FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLENAME'`. If the result isn't NULL it's index-organized.

Comment: The result is NULL on both tables.

Comment: Please preserve the formatting from the explain output. The indention is important to analyze it.

Comment: Do you have fresh statistics on those table? Maybe gather them with greater sample?

Comment: You should re-paste the explain plan leave more of the details in, and indentation (as per @a_horse_with_no_name) substituting your dummy table/index names for the real ones. Step 1 & 2 should be unnested access of table2 but it is a `UNIQUE SCAN` where I was guessing the (param1, param2) index was non-unique. Step 3 is a `RANGE SCAN` but these should be using the (t2.key1, t2.key2) pairs to access the primary key of table1, a unique scan by definition. The additional info will help clarify this confusion. It looks like its not unnesting the sub-query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

Your each delete call, running a query in table 2 on 30m records, which definitely degrade performance and may also create locking issue, which in turn again slow down the query.

I suggest to move out inline query which is selecting data from table2. Table2 should be driving the delete and have delete candidate records. It can run as a cursor or place this data in temporary table. Let delete be executed in chunk of 500 , 1000 and followed by commit. This chunk can be optimized based on results.

Index update during delete is not redundant, if this process is running in non working hours, you may disable index and recreate again..

Answer (score 0):

I think so if the outer query is "small" and the inner query is "big" -- a WHERE EXISTS can be quite efficient.

Try where exists clause instead of In clause then check for the explain plan and the performance.

```
DELETE FROM table1 t1
WHERE
Exists (select 1 
   FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.parm1 = 1234
 AND t2.parm2 = 5678
 AND t2.key1 = t1.key1
 AND t2.key2 = t1.key2
)
```